# How to get containing Node Name from xml namespace

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I've got XPath of XML with it's structure like

```
 <Statement xsi:type="conditionStatement">
    <Id>CONDITION_0001</Id>
    <Bounds>
        <xValue>13</xValue>
        <yValue>145</yValue>
        <Height>402</Height>
        <Width>513</Width>
    </Bounds>
.........
.........
</statement>
```

Xpath takes me to xsi:type. But when I'm trying to get the name of node which is "statement" as expected, it's getting null.

My code for this is:-

```
nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(xPathSrcFile).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
nodeList.item(i).getParentNode();
}
```

For rest of the cases, code is working perfectly fine but when it gets to "xsi", code is throwing nullpointer exception.

Need some help to get node name from this.

Comment: Have you defined the `xsi` namespace in the processing-instruction at the beginning? [When using prefixes in XML, a namespace for the prefix must be defined.](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
NodeList nodeList = null;
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
InputStream inputStream= new FileInputStream(file);//xmlDocument as file
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"ISO-8859-1");
InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);
is.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
Document doc = db.parse(is);
Element docEle = doc.getDocumentElement();
nodeList = docEle.getElementsByTagName("Statement");
```

Answer (score 0):

1 Your XML file is incorrect:

it begins with Statement

and ends with /statement

2 you need this at root tag:

< root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >

3 to get the name of you tag, use:
nodeList.item(i).getTagName();

4 what is your Xpath ?